# Conga - Multiple Queries

Tags: query, conga, conga-composer

My new company uses Conga Composer for a lot of different reporting.

One of these reports is a weekly sales report that my manager is having to run one by one for each rep (MergeLink for each rep).

I set up a single MergeLink for this report that would pass the Salesforce report parameters and allowed the logged in user to generate a report for themselves. Turns out the sales manager doesn't want them having export access which messes up MergeLink when it tries to run the report and pull that data.

After speaking with support they suggested that I go the query route. I know very little about queries but am confident I can figure it out with the query builder. My concern is I will need to do multiple queries and can't seem to find good info on how I would nest multiple queries into one button/link.

Ideally, I'd like the sales users to be able to click a custom link from their Home sidebar which would open Composer and run the merge template.

Answer (score 4):

It's really simple, but I couldn't find a solid help document in the conga site (I often can't).

You pass multiple query ids to the `queryid` parameter, and each query will be run and added to the data returned for use in the conga template.

Example from my production org:

```
&queryid=a0gU0000001XIYD,a0gU0000001XIZw,a0gU0000001XIa1
```

Each query will show up in its own results table, which can be visualized really well by following these steps to access the data of the queries:

1. Open a conga window by clicking on a button/link configured to open a conga window
2. Click on Tools & Settings
3. Click View Data

You'll end up with an excel sheet with your query data, and each query will be on its own tab in the sheet. To access this data in merge fields, you'll need to specify which table you are trying to access, such as:

```
«TableStart:QueryData»«ACCOUNT_NAME»«TableEnd:QueryData»
«TableStart:QueryData2»«PRICEBOOKENTRY_NAME»«TableEnd:QueryData2»
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get all of this figured out and have a working link. The last part I'm trying to figure out now is how/if I can pass user info to each Query. This would allow each user to click the link, query for only their data, and merge the report.

Comment: See [this conga help doc](https://support.getconga.com/Conga_Composer/Composer_Essentials/Gathering_Data_for_Composer/13_Advanced_Conga_Queries) for advanced query creation techniques, including how to use `pv0` as a query filter for your records. If you have a more detailed question, I'd recommend asking a second question over extending your first questions scope via comments.